# java.security.AccessControlException while running java web application on hosting server

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

My JSP/Servlet code runs well in localhost but when I host my code in server, I encounter the following error:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "GCMRegId.txt" "read")
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: give the user who is running your server the proper permission to write the file

Comment: as Leo said,you can change permissions in Unix by chmod comman(4-read,2-write,1 execute) o the appropriate group

Comment: Thanks you very much. But I do not know where I can config permission. It the first time I work with jsp. Sorry about that. And I hope your assitance

Answer (score 1):

Your server environment is using a SecurityManager that is preventing access to that file. You'll need to talk to the server admins about granting your application the permissions it needs to run.